# cancelOperation not called in NSView subclass

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, keydown, esc-key

`cancelOperation:` is not being called in my bare-bones `NSView` subclass when I press Esc.

I checked and the Esc key is received on `keyDown`. Also, other action messages (such as `moveLeft`) are being called.

The view is part of a Window shown like this:

```
[self.window addChildWindow:wc.window ordered:NSWindowAbove];
[wc.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have an app with a couple of `NSWindow`s. I had to call 
`[self.window makeFirstResponder:self]` in my `NSView` subclass to have the view respond to `cancelOperation:`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing it as `cancelOperation` or `cancelOperation:`? There's a big difference. The method signature should be:

```
- (void)cancelOperation:(id)sender
```

This works for me with a vanilla `NSView`.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're implementing `keyDown:` but then not calling `interpretKeyEvents:` inside your implementation. You either need to not implement `keyDown:` or make sure you call `[self interpretKeyEvents:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theEvent]]` inside your implementation.

Comment: No, I'm not implementing keyDown:. I just tested that Esc was being received, then removed it.

Answer (score 0):

My derived `NSView` had the same problem. It was resolved after implementing `acceptsFirstResponder` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```